# How to integrate Bootstrap material design in Sass based Angular4 application

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-material-design

I am trying to integrate bootstrap-material-design into my sass based angular4 application.

It works perfectly fine with the precompiled css. But I would like to use the sass version of the bootstrap-material-design.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **step by step method** to use **Material Design with Bootstrap 4 using Sass**

> follow the below given steps for configuration or
>    https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/5min-quickstart/

**Step 1**:  Create new angular project using Angular CLI command:

```
ng new your-angular-project --style=scss
```

**Step 2**:

```
cd your-angular-project
```

**Step 3**:  GitHub npm install

```
npm i angular-bootstrap-md --save
```

**Step 4**: to app.module.ts add

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
    ],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
});
```

**Step 5**: Make sure that styleExt is set to "scss" in angular-cli.json file, if not change:

```
"styleExt": "css" to "styleExt": "scss"
```

**Step 6**:

Make sure you have . If you have src/styles.css instead, rename it to .scss.

if you want to change styles in existing project you can use ng set defaults.styleExt scss

**Step 7**: add below lines to angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
    "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
    "./styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
  "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
],
```

**Step 8**: Update ts.config.json file, add following into tsconfig.json file located in root folder

```
"include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts",  "src/**/*.ts"],
```

**Step 9**: install external libs

```
npm install -–save chart.js@2.5.0 font-awesome hammerjs
```

**Step 10**: Run server

```
ng serve --open
```

for documentation, https://mdbootstrap.com/, after opening this page, go down you'll find like that and click to see documentation

[image]